# AWS Automated DBSnapshot (System) in CloudTrail event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot, amazon-cloudtrail, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I'm looking at triggering a lambda when a new automated DB Snapshot is available in RDS (System ones instead of Manual ones). Although after digging in CloudTrail, I don't see any events marked as follow (AWS Sample):

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "844e2571-85d4-695f-b930-0153b71dcb42",
  "detail-type": "RDS DB Snapshot Event",
  "source": "aws.rds",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2018-10-06T12:26:13Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": ["arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24"],
  "detail": {
    "EventCategories": ["creation"],
    "SourceType": "SNAPSHOT",
    "SourceArn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24",
    "Date": "2018-10-06T12:26:13.882Z",
    "SourceIdentifier": "rds:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24",
    "Message": "Automated snapshot created"
  }
}
```

Thanks again if you know which AWS Events I should lookup for :)

Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudtrail won't give you such information. I would go with the flow highlighted bellow

**RDS (event notification) -> SNS -> Lambda**

You need to have an SNS topic as source of your lambda, because RDS fans out its events to this service

Check what RDS document [states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html)

> Amazon RDS uses the Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) to provide notification when an Amazon RDS event occurs

Regarding the notification itself, I could see that the [DB snapshot event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html#USER_Events.Messages.snapshot) event bellow might be the one that you're looking for

| Category | RDS event ID | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| creation | RDS-EVENT-0091 | An automated DB snapshot is being created. |

Comment: Aaah that makes a lot more sense now, thank you Victor, that was the right information I was looking for :)